# Social identity auth using Azure AD B2C for google doesnt show permission request page but facebook does.

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Social identity auth using Azure AD B2C for Google doesn't show permission request page but Facebook does.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Am i missing something here.

Comment: Are you talking about the Consent page? Or are you saying that Google just doesn't work at all with your Azure AD B2C setup? Can you please add more details to your question: error messages, screenshots, http requests, etc. Otherwise it's really had to help you out.

Comment: I guess have figured this out. The app was already authenticated using the Google account and hence Google doesn't ask for the consent. For checking this have used Facebook as an example and deleted the app permission from Facebook and Azure User profile. then it straight away showed the consent page on sign-up.  So i could have just deleted the user from Azure leave the permission from social identity providers.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD B2C does not require consent.

The only consent experience you might go through in Azure AD B2C is when signing up / signing in with social accounts.

As part of setting up a social IdP in Azure AD B2C, you must register an application in the social IdP (see this example on [how to do it for Facebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-fb-app)). Users will have to consent to that app in their social IdP the very first time the sign in. This consent enforced and maintained by the social IdP, so even if you delete the user in Azure AD B2C, recreating the user in Azure AD B2C using the same app registration will not re-trigger consent.